# Spring Dynamic Loading Dao

Tags: java, spring, dao

I have been working on springboot application, it contains more than 10 datasource, called Multi-tenant。

At the beginning, I didn’t know which database to query data from. I only got the database configuration based on the http request parameters and established the database connection, so the dao compontents could not be loaded when the spring application was initialized.

Then when I got the database connection, how to dynamically inject dao component ?

Also, the next http request may obtain information from another database, and I have to inject this dao component again based on this database connection

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your application is structured, but for similar use case we inject the bean with `@Requestscope` (code is for Google Datastore, where namespace is resolved dynamically based on request)

```
  @Bean
  @RequestScope
  public DatastoreNamespaceProvider datastoreNamespaceProvider() {
    return () -> namespaceProvider().getNamespace();
  }
```

Where `namespaceProvider()`is again a bean with `@Requestscope`, which reads value from API http request.